# Show contact name from the contact id column stored in my invoice table in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm obviously new at developing with Ruby on Rails 4. I have a Company model, a Contact model and an Invoice model. Contacts are nested into Companies, and Invoices are nested into Companpies. My Invoice table has a column for contact_id, which is is stored in my invoice table based on a drop down menu that is populated from `@company.contacts`. Instead of displaying `@invoice.contact_id` (i.e. 10), I'd like to show `contact_id` 10's name from the contact table.
I'm pretty sure I need to define `@contacts` in the invoice controller but can't seem to find the right syntax that says get the name of the `contact_id` where `contact.id = @invoice.contact_id`.

**Routes.rb**:

```
resources :companies do
  resources :contacts 
  resources :invoices 
end
```

**Company.rb**:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices
  has_many :contacts
end
```

**Contact.rb**:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

**Invoice.rb**:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :company 
  has_many :contacts, through: :company 
end
```

**Schema.rb**

```
create_table "companies", force: true do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.string   "street"
t.string   "city"
t.string   "province"
t.string   "postal_code"
t.string   "tel"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end
create_table "contacts", force: true do |t|
t.integer  "company_id"
t.string   "first_name"
t.string   "last_name"
t.string   "title"
t.string   "tel"
t.string   "email"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "contacts", ["company_id"], name: "index_contacts_on_company_id", using: :btree

create_table "invoices", force: true do |t|
t.integer  "company_id"
t.integer  "contact_id"
t.integer  "item_id"
t.decimal  "total",      precision: 7, scale: 2
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end
  add_index "invoices", ["company_id"], name: "index_invoices_on_company_id", using: :btree
add_index "invoices", ["contact_id"], name: "index_invoices_on_contact_id", using: :btre
add_index "invoices", ["item_id"], name: "index_invoices_on_item_id", using: :btree
```

Comment: Could you post your schema? I think you have got your association worng. If `invoice` has `contact_id`, `invoice` should `belong_to contact`

Comment: I've added my shcema to my original post

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to achieve with Rails:

```
# controller
def index
  @invoices = Invoice.all.includes(:contacts) # .inclutes(:contacts) is Eager Loading (n+1 Queries)
end

# view
@invoices.each do |invoice|
  invoice.contacts.each do |contact|
    contact.name
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks @MrYoshiji that worked. It lists all the contact names. but it this case, I want to just show the name of the contact_id in the invoice table, so if contact_id in my invoice table is 10, I want to display the name of that contact 10 from the contacts table